# flash upload button not wroking for more than one field on a page

Tags: javascript

i have taken a code from http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/ where multiple file upload is possible, i have integrated the code in my project, but here my issue is my form is created dynamically by the user, so field name is dynamic, in such case  my js function having an id as #swfupload-control and button_placeholder : $('#button)[0], only works for a single input type button, and other buttons are blank as they are getting the id but not working

Comment: Please tell us where we can see your code. A jsfiddle or editing your question with the code would be helpful.

Comment: http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/multiple-file-upload-with-progress-bar-using-jquery/ if u download from this link u will get an index.phmtl wherein if u add another input type=button u dont see an upload flash button, thus the issue is how to display more than one upload button dyanmically without writing the script again and again

Comment: $(function(){
 $('#swfupload-control').swfupload({
  upload_url: "upload-file.php",
  file_post_name: 'uploadfile',
  file_size_limit : "1024",
  file_types : "*.jpg;*.png;*.gif",
  file_types_description : "Image files",
  file_upload_limit : 5,
  flash_url : "js/swfupload/swfupload.swf",
  button_image_url : 'js/swfupload/wdp_buttons_upload_114x29.png',
  button_width : 114,
  button_height : 29,
  button_placeholder : $('#button')[0],
  debug: false
 })</script>  <input type="button" id="button" />